# Cannot access http server (apache2 on Webmin) from WAN

Tags: apache, http, raspberry-pi, webmin

I've already opened the port 80. It worked perfectly, but after some changes it left working. Webmin runs on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.

**1.** I tried to solve an ip issue, because my router changed my ip so quick that I had to update my ip on my Webmin server every time it changed.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMYlD.png)

**2.** So I decided to change the ip to `127.0.0.1` in all of my servers. Like this:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVXhv.png)

**3.** Then, cause now I could't access to my server from outside of my LAN. I tried to reset my eth0 ip again as it was in all of my servers (as `192.168.1.89`), but it didn't work. I still can't access my http from outside.

**4.** I waited my eth0 ip to change to update it again (to put it instead of `127.0.0.1`), but didn't work. I tried to do it like this: [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t27CZ.png)

As I said, it worked perfectly before changing the ip to `127.0.0.1`, because my normal ip changes too fast (every 7 or 10 mins). I can access to my http server but only from my LAN.

Comment: You could assign a static IP address in your router to avoid it changing ever.

Comment: Yeah, but that’s not the problem. My router uses MAC address for opening ports, not IP address. So if I put my public IP address I’m supposed to see what’s inside of my HTTP server, even if my local IP changed. But I can’t see anything, I configured port mapping in my router but still have the same problem, which I didn’t have 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found the solution. The problem was nothing about my Apache or Webmin configuration. It was about a problem with my router. Apparently it had a bug: The `DMZ` seemed as activated, but it really didn't (my router is a `HUAWEI HG659`).

Also, if you get this kind of problem, you should first check what ports are being used by your computer, and check if you have any firewall or program blocking that port.